# How to get a .png of the Desktop background "color"

Tags: desktop-background, appearance

In Ubuntu 16.04 settings, you can go to Appearance > Colors & Gradients > and select a 'plain' color to be the Desktop background. I like the color choices of 16.04 and want to use the same color on Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop background but 18.04 doesn't offer the same color.

Is there a way to save a .png of Ubuntu Desktop color background on 16.04 so I can have a .png of that color for use on 18.04?

Comment: so your question is how to know the back ground color that you have set as background in Ubuntu 16.04 rite?

Comment: `kcolorchooser` will let you pick any colour on screen and give you the RGB code, which you can then set as background colour.

Answer (score 3):

#### How to copy over the solid color

You probably won't need to get it as a file. What to do?

1. On 16.04, open a terminal window, run the command:

   ```
   dconf watch /
   ```
2. Still on 16.04, set the plain color you like. In the terminal, you'll see something like:

   ```
   jacob@jacob-Aspire-Z3-705:~$ dconf watch /
   /org/gnome/desktop/background/color-shading-type
     'solid'
   /org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-options
     'wallpaper'
   /org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri
     'file:////usr/share/gnome-control-center/pixmaps/noise-texture-light.png'
   /org/gnome/desktop/background/primary-color
     '#425265'
   /org/gnome/desktop/background/secondary-color
     '#425265'
   ```
3. The two last values are the ones to copy, now on 18.04, simply set a (any) solid color, subsequentlu run the two commands:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#425265'
   ```

   and

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background secondary-color '#425265'
   ```

   where '#425265' is the color you read on 16.04

#### Alternatively, just set the color on 16.04 and read it directly from

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background secondary-color
```

and

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color
```

Comment: This is excellent answer, but it didn't work. I was able to change the color via gsettings but the orange color# I took from 16.04 (e.g., #f5f579790000) produces black on 18.04. I tried some other color#s and they all are black. Do you know a way to make the 16.04 color# work on 18.04?

Comment: @G.W. was  #f5f579790000 the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color` ? If so, that is extremely odd, that isn't even a valid color (should have six figures)

Comment: Yes, that was the color at the gsettings ... primary-color. I tested the process activating different colors also. The color at gsettings always changed number and the number produced was always longer than the number on 18.04.

Comment: @G.W. are you on Unity? I'll set up a VM to find out what is going on if so.

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu Desktop (Unity) on 16.04. And Ubuntu Desktop on 18.04. The specific "color" I am trying to get is #2e2e34343636 (the darkest gray color that Unity offers in the solid color desktop backgrounds).